# What is a non-local return?

Tags: function, programming-languages

What is non local return? In what scenarios it is useful? Please give an example to explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means exiting a function and ending up someplace else beside where the function was called. It's primarily used to refer to *exceptions* (i.e., `try`, `throw`, and `catch` in Java and C++), but it can also mean mechanisms like `setjmp/longjmp` in C.

Answer (score 17):

[Here's a good article](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/07/the-building-blocks-of-ruby/) on the use of non local returns in the context of ruby blocks.

> Ruby’s blocks support non-local-return (some references), which means
>   that a return from the block behaves identically to returning from the
>   block’s original context.

It basically mean that you can call a block from a function, and the block has the ability to return from the original function.

Answer (score 2):

Non-Local returns are the default in Smalltalk. To understand why, you need to understand how control-structures are defined in Smalltalk.

In Smalltalk "everything is an object". That includes blocks, too. Luckily this doesn't sound as weird nowadays as it would have sounded in the 90s and early 2000s.
Add to this the fact that Blocks are super easy to declare, there are some non-obvious consequences to this:

- there is no "syntax" for control structure
- control structures are really just APIs provided by the objects, not by the parser/compiler

Consider the following if-statement (return-statements in Smalltalk are done via `^`):

```
factorialOf: aNumber
  aNumber <= 1 ifTrue:[^1].
  ^aNumber * (self factorialOf: aNumber - 1)
```

In Javascript you'd write this function like so:

```js
function factorialOf(aNumber)
{
   if (aNumber <= 1) return 1;
   return aNumber * factorialOf(aNumber - 1);
}
```

The difference between the Smalltalk-Implementation and the Javascript implementation is that in Smalltalk `[^1]` is actually a Block that makes the method return 1. Technically this may sound super complicated but from a programmers point of view (in the `#factorialOf:` method) it's the obvious thing to do.

---

**NOTE**
`ifTrue:` is implemented in the class `Boolean`. It takes a block as argument and only `Boolean`'s subclass `True` would evaluate this block. Due to optimisations, the compiler would inline the block though (but you can still send it as message, if you would want to).

---

If you extend the idea of control structures to the following code, where blocks are used to define what should happen if something is not available, you see that there's nothing special about non-local returns (at least in Smalltalk).

```
someMethod
   | value |
   value := aDictionary at: myKey ifAbsent:[^nil].
   ^value doSomething
```

Again, the non-local-return allows the method, where the block is defined to simply perform an early return. The method that evaluates the Block doesn't need to know about the non-local-return, it'll just stop its execution.

The obvious question now is: how do blocks return values to their caller? They simply always return the value of their last statement, whether the caller is interested in it or not.

The following example will return all even numbers between 1 and 20.

```
(1 to: 20) select:[:each | each even]
```

Here the block returns whether the number is even. The caller (`#select:`) will then use this boolean to decide if that number should be included in its result or not.

---

In comparison to other programming languages where Blocks/Closures are more like anonymous functions (that were typically added after the language was introduced), their return semantics are exactly like in normal functions: you specify the return value of the Block/Closure.

As blocks are used in Smalltalk on such a fundamental level, you cannot make the language work without non-local-returns.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the matter here is some sample code to explain what non-local returns are.

```
object Scratch {
    def foo: Int = {
        val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
        list.foreach { each =>
            if(each > 2) {
                return each // NLR
            }
            println(each)
    }
    return 5   
}


def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val i = foo
    println("i: " + i)   
}
```

The code above is in Scala, but things would be essential the same for any other language that supports non-local returns such as Kotlin and most prominently Smalltalk and Ruby (I think also most functional programming languages as well such as List).

The point is here that the code above would write this output to the console:

```
1
2
i: 3
```

So it does not print 4 and 5 to the console as well and that is in this example the big difference to languages that do not support non-local returns from within closures.

In the code snippet above the return at line "NLR" returns out of the closure >>and<< out of the function that invoked the closure. This is the difference to a local return which would return out of the closure but execution would thereafter continue at the next line after the closure in the same method that invoked the closure. The non-local return is in that sense not a local return any more, but an "uber" local return. However, it is somehow called non-local return.

In languages without non-local returns such as Java or C# the code above would be rejected by the compiler. In Java a plain return from within a lambda (just a return without returning a value) has the same effect as a continue.

Non-local returns cost a bit extra CPU time (which to my knowledge is very little) but also result in allocation on the heap as closures with a non-local return cannot be allocated on the stack any more. This is because such a closure can be passed over to other functions (that might be in a different thread as well). So closures that support non-local returns consume a bit more heap space.

When a non-local return is done from the function the closure was passed over to, the thread of execution jumps out of that function as displayed in the sample code here is well. I think this is the reason why many functional programming language support non-local returns as passing functions over as a parameter to other functions is a common way of doing things in functional programming.

Why are non-local returns an issue? Because you want to be able to return out of a closure just the same way you do from a for loop or while loop or a plain function. If that is not possible for a closure, the entire code that was written with closures to begin with has to rewritten once some non-local return needs to be done with a for or while loop. In that case the expressiveness of closures would be lost.

Comment: Note that this feature is deprecated in scala3 ( see https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/nonlocal-returns.html )

Comment: @Amit Portnoy: That is correct and it really causes me grieve :-(. I tried to talk to the Scala people about it by making a post in the Scala language forum but got no answer.

Comment: Well it's not completely gone, you need to wrap in `returning` and use `throwReturn` (
https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/util/control/NonLocalReturns$.html ). They try to make the underlying expception usage more explicit.
Also note you will have continuations that make this kind of behaviour more structured. (https://github.com/rssh/dotty-cps-async)