# Non-local return in Perl (return from the caller)

Tags: perl

Is there a way for me to return *from* my caller instead of *to* my caller? e.g.

```
sub foo {
    bar();
    # this never gets executed
}

sub bar {
    return_from_caller(5);
}

# This prints 5
print foo();
```

(Rationale: I am writing a function memoize_self that memoizes a function from within the function itself. I'd like it to work like this:

```
sub complex_function {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    memoize_self({key => $y, expires_in => '5min'));
    # compute $result
    return $result;
}
```

memoize_self will check its cache, and if it gets a hit, return the cached value *from* its caller. Otherwise, it will re-call the function (with a dynamically scoped var to avoid the obvious infinite loop), store the return value in the cache and again return it.

Without the ability to return from caller, I'd probably use $_ and write it this way:

```
return $_ if memoize_self({key => $y, expires_in => '5min'));
```

But this is extra noise, and also doesn't take context into account.)

EDIT: To the people who reasonably suggested [Memoize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Memoize) - yes, I should have said, I know this module well. I'm writing a more modern and featureful version of Memoize based on [CHI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CHI).

But as relates to this question, there are cases where it's useful to memoize from *within* the function rather than *outside* the function (Memoize only does the latter). It makes it easy to customize the cache key and/or determine whether you want to memoize at all for this particular call. e.g.

```
sub complex_function {
    my $key = ...;   # normalize arguments
    if (...) {       # is it worth memoizing in this case?
        memoize_self({key => $key});
    }
}
```

I also like the way it is wrapped up in the function instead of creating its own line outside, ala [state variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html).

Comment: Related: [COMEFROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM) (:

Comment: This kind of [non-local return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897507/what-is-a-non-local-return) is possible with [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) but this is awkward in perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Continuation::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Continuation::Escape) does exactly what you want. [Memoize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Memoize) is what you really need, however, as Nikhil pointed out.

Comment: Thanks Hans! "use Scope::Upper qw(unwind UP);" and then "unwind (5, UP)" does exactly what I want in the example above.

Comment: In addition to accepting @Hans' answer, you should vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to CPAN module [Memoize](https://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize) - Make functions faster by trading space for time, this will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a way for me to return from my caller instead of to my caller?"

Yes, there are several.

- You can use `goto` to jump back. See `perldoc -f goto`.
- You can use `eval` and `die` for a more control jump. See `perldoc -f eval` and `perldoc -f die`.
- Instead of calling your sub in the normal way, you can `goto` it. When you do this, it will return to the sub with the `goto` caller. See `perldoc -f goto`.

Of course, most people would tell you to rewrite everything to avoid gotos and make life easier for those maintaining your code but what have they ever done for you?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the Want module's double_return method, which makes your next return pop off two call frames:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Want;

sub foo {
    Want::double_return;
    return 11;
}
sub bar { 
    foo();
    # never executed
    return 55;
}

# prints 11;
print bar();
```

Comment: I don't see `double_return` listed on `Want`'s documentation. It does appear to be an internal function, but lacking documentation it shouldn't be relied upon to continue working as it does now.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure why I even remembered it.